# Wireless problems on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 12.04, wireless, laptop

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 on my laptop. When I try to connect to my Wireless it keeps trying but doesn't connect. My phone works fine. I've tried to look it up but no luck, any suggestions?

Ps: I also tried to connect the wire directly to the laptop, still tries but fails

I'm using a Samsung NP300E4C-S01

Edit: for some wired reason, now it connects to my router but I don't have Internet access.

Ps: I didn't delete my windows 7 yet

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the laptop model (at least the wireless card model).

Comment: Added laptop model, how exactly can I check wireless card model?

Comment: Open a terminal and run `lspci | grep -i 'Network\|Wireless'` and add the output to your question.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: For some wired reason, it connected to my router. But I don't have Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check if :

- Your router's and client's dhcp settings are the same (auto-dhcp / manual ip)
- Your router hasnt any mac-filter lists enabled
- You are running a firewall on your Laptop (firestarter,upf etc)
- look for fresh drivers for your network card

Comment: I only edited formatting, you'll have to ask @tuxaddict.

Comment: oh my bad

@tuxaddict Its set to auto what do u exactly mean by mac filters enabled? i tried to turn the firewall off and reboot, same prob. where do i look for correct fresh drivers?

Comment: @Amiroslo : a router can filter accsess only to given mac-adresses of certain networkcards, that can be a reason why a new client can not connect (if the mac filter list isnt updated with the new client) but in ur case if u say u have a firewall running that may be part of the problem.  if u disable ur fw and reboot that does NOT MEAN that the corresponding iptables are changed or resets, they are still present ! so u may chk ur iptables directly, reset them (my suggestion) or chk them using ur firewalls gui.u may wanna look for fresh drivers on the manufactures page of ur NIC (hardware).(-: